# Get specific property value from derived object represented by IDebugProperty2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-extensions

The custom tool window of a Visual Studio Extension package uses the debug engine to evaluate custom expressions. The evaluation works fine via `IDebugStackFrame2` -> `IDebugExpressionContext2` and gives the expression result as `IDebugProperty2`.

The result represents a complex custom object. In order to handle it further, a specific property of its *base* class needs to get retrieved. I tried using `IDebugProperty2.EnumChildren()` in the hope, it would also give inherited fields/properties. But it doesn't (?)

What is the best approach for accessing a field of a base class from IDebugProperty2 ?

Walking along the heritance hirarchy up to the base class and fetch the property from there - similar to the usage in the locals window ? Or is there a smarter approach?